# Liquibase migration not working on Spring Boot 2.4.3 application startup

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase

I have updated Spring Boot version to `2.4.3`. After the upgrade, liquibase migrations are not working. No error messages or logs also seen for this.

I have the following properties set in my application.yaml

```
spring:
  liquibase:
     change-log: classpath:liquibase/changelog.xml
```

Is any other change required in the newer spring boot upgrades?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the order in which the beans were getting executed. Redis bean was getting executed before liquibase and failing.